# What would be the best way to track Github account activity via their API?

Tags: python, django

So after searching through various resources over the internet I have come to a point where I need a third opinion.

The problem statement: I would like to integrate my user's GitHub account activity inside app. I would mainly like to alert my user when events occur under his GitHub account, such as when a repo is created, deleted or pushed to or when a new user is added to a team or on organization.

So far, I am able to retrieve few of this events from the GitHub developer API.

https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/

There are two problems with this.

1. It doesn't include some of the events such as when a repository is deleted.
2. It doesn't include the event source location/ip address - which is one of the most important thing that I need.

I know that, For enterprise domains github provides "audit-log" functionality which has almost all the information I need to achieve the resolution for my task, However these "audit-logs" are not exposed via the developer API. (Is this correct?)

[Related stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578477/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-audit-log-in-github-com-via-the-api)

My questions are,

1. What would be the best approach to get these events with their source location/country (like audit-logs) into my app.
2. Is there a way to retrieve this audit-logs somehow? Are there any libraries available that may help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your repository is part of [an organization](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-organizations), you could, starting  May 23rd 2019 (4 years later), use the **[Audit Log API](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-05-23-audit-log-api/)**

> Today we’re introducing the public beta of the Audit Log API.
>   As a GitHub Enterprise Cloud organization administrator, you can now access log events using our GraphQL API and monitor the activity in your organization.

As explained in "[Using the Audit log API](https://help.github.com/en/articles/reviewing-the-audit-log-for-your-organization#using-the-audit-log-api)", this is only, for now, reserved to organizations using [GitHub Enterprise](https://help.github.com/en/articles/githubs-products#github-enterprise).

See "[GraphQL API Audit Log preview](https://developer.github.com/v4/previews/#audit-log)", for the exact API.

Comment: Important to stress this is only relevant, both on the GraphQL and the REST API, to the  Enterprise license.. which is a bit of a shame.

Comment: @JAR.JAR.beans Indeed. That is what I meant with "this is only, for now, reserved to organizations using GitHub Enterprise."